# Nodejs- Req.body undefined in put with express

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

while request a put request from axios in react and check the req in backend i got it empty i have used fuction like this

I have searched for several solution and found out that using body-parser it will work but in my case it doesn't  and any rearrangement doesn't work

i have already used bodyparser before routers

my create, delete, read req are working fine the problem i face in put req only
i am using latest express bodyparser axios reactjs

please help me out

````
    console.log(JSON.stringify(brand)); here it is printing whole data 
    return fetch(`${API}/brand/${brandId}/${userId}`,{
        method:"PUT",
        headers:{
            Accept:"application/json",
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            Authorization:`Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(brand),
    }).then(response=>{
        console.log(response);
        return response.json()
    }).catch(err=> console.log(err))
}


exports.updateBrand=(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)//here it is printing {}
    const brand = req.brand;
    brand.name=req.body.name;
    brand.save((err,updatedbrand)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:"Failed to update"
            })
        }
        res.json(updatedbrand)
    })
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is caused by the fact that you haven't set `body-parser` middleware on the express app.  As explain in the express [Request documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req)

> **req.body** Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is **undefined**, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// other settings goes here

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
// and so on
```

Comment: as I already mentioned i have used middleware bodyparser and at req i got an empty data